# Getting IntelliJ to import shaded dependencies in a multi-module maven project

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I have two modules, Component and Application. The Component module is shaded due to a dependency conflict (google protocol buffers) later in the build process.

```
<!-- snip from Component's pom.xml -->
<plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>2.3</version>
     <configuration>
         <relocations>
             <relocation>
                 <pattern>com.google.protobuf</pattern>                                
                 <shadedPattern>my.package.protocols.shaded.com.google.protobuf</shadedPattern>
             </relocation>
         </relocations>
     </configuration>
     <executions>
         <execution>
             <phase>package</phase>
             <goals>
                 <goal>shade</goal>
             </goals>
         </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

The Application depends on the Component module. However, source files in the Application cannot reference the shaded library that the Component depends on. This is critical for interacting with the Component.

```
     <-- snip from Application's pom.xml -->   
     <dependency>
          <groupId>my-group</groupId>
          <artifactId>component</artifactId>
          <version>${project.version}</version>
     </dependency>
```

Even though the import can't be found by IntelliJ, the Maven build works fine. What am I missing/doing-wrong?

Comment: I am having the same problem too (precisely the same situation you described). In other SO posts, they advise to go to File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart. I have seen this work at times and not at times (this time, it doesn't work). For example, for an earlier branch, invalidating the cache and restarting works, but for another branch, this doesn't work. I am wondering myself how to correct this problem.

Comment: I ended up separating the shaded module out into it's own project. Certainly not a universal solution but it ended up working better in our case for CI reasons. However, I'm leaving the Q open in hopes that there is another solution. If not I'll open a ticket with JetBrains.

Comment: did you have a chance to open a ticket with JetBrains? i'm still stuck.. unfortunately, i'm on a big project, and don't have the option to refactor the maven module out into its own project.

Comment: I have not as I am on vacation this week. Feel free to open one if it's more urgent.

Comment: Which version of IntelliJ are you using?

Comment: Whenever I use maven-shade-plugin, I normally use JD-GUI or 7zip to verify the resulting Component JAR and check to make sure it is as expected. Is your Component.jar correct ? Did the protobuf package & classes make it inside the final JAR ?

Answer (score 10):

Too bad, after opening a ticket with JetBrains, this problem has been previously reported and is currently not supported in IntelliJ.

- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-126596
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-93855

Comment: In the first ticket, the last comment give a good workaround which works for me:  A better workaround seems to be: Right-click on shade-bug-repackaged -> pom.xml in the project view in IntelliJ, choose "Maven" -> "Ignore Projects". Then do a "Maven" -> "Reimport" on the top-level pom.xml.

Answer (score 5):

build-helper-maven-plugin seems to add the shaded jar into IntelliJ project:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>compile</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>attach-artifact</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <artifacts>
            <artifact>
              <file>${basedir}/target/<YOUR JAR NAME>-SNAPSHOT.jar</file>
              <type>jar</type>
              <classifier>optional</classifier>
            </artifact>
          </artifacts> 
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

For details, see https://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/attach-artifact-mojo.html.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed the similar problem by shading also a source jar and unpacking it to the source directory:

```
<build>

    <sourceDirectory>${project.build.directory}/shaded-sources</sourceDirectory>

    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <skipSource>true</skipSource>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <createSourcesJar>true</createSourcesJar>
              <shadeSourcesContent>true</shadeSourcesContent>
              <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
              <artifactSet>
                <includes>
                  <include>com.google.guava:*</include>
                </includes>
              </artifactSet>
              <relocations>
                <relocation>
                  <pattern>com.google.common</pattern>
                  <shadedPattern>org.apache.drill.shaded.com.google.common</shadedPattern>
                </relocation>
              </relocations>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>unpack</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>unpack</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <artifactItems>
                <artifactItem>
                  <groupId>org.apache.drill.contrib</groupId>
                  <artifactId>guava-shaded</artifactId>
                  <version>${project.version}</version>
                  <type>jar</type>
                  <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</outputDirectory>
                  <includes>**/**</includes>
                </artifactItem>
                <artifactItem>
                  <groupId>org.apache.drill.contrib</groupId>
                  <artifactId>guava-shaded</artifactId>
                  <version>${project.version}</version>
                  <type>jar</type>
                  <classifier>sources</classifier>
                  <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                  <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/shaded-sources</outputDirectory>
                  <includes>**/**</includes>
                </artifactItem>
              </artifactItems>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
</build>
```

Answer (score 2):

A better workaround seems to be: Right-click on shard project "component" -> pom.xml in the project view in IntelliJ, choose "Maven" -> "Ignore Projects". Then do a "Maven" -> "Reimport" on the project pom.xml.

Answer (score 0):

One more solution I'm using in the current project.

It works the same way for both shaded modules or custom bundles.

```
<!--
  - Make sure 'module-a' is built BEFORE this module
  -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
    <artifactId>module-a</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope><!-- or runtime -->
</dependency>

<!--
  - IDEA does NOT support custom bundles in multi-module projects.
  - Using system scope to link correct JAR file explicitly.
 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
    <artifactId>module-a</artifactId>
    <version>FAKE-VERSION</version>
    <classifier>FAKE-CLASSIFIER</classifier>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${project.basedir}/../module-a/target/module-a-${project.version}.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

As a complement to TimP's answer:

- By attach additional artifact using `build-helper-maven-plugin`, the `Idea` is able to recognized it and work fine as an transitive dependency(other modules dependent on the artifact recognize relocated symbols as well).

  [image]
- If you don't want to package the additional artifact, simply add `skipAttach` to the `execution` configuration(The shaded artifact still recognized by `IDEA`):

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
           <id>attach-shade-jar</id>
           <phase>package</phase>
           <goals>
              <goal>attach-artifact</goal>
           </goals>
           <configuration>
               <artifacts>
                  <artifact>   
  <file>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.jar</file>
                      <type>jar</type>
                      <classifier>shaded</classifier>
                  </artifact>
               </artifacts>
               <skipAttach>true</skipAttach>
          </configuration>
      </execution>
   </executions>
</plugin>
```